# What's the difference between y(x) and a in the cost function from neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com book

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm reading **Neural Networks and Deep Learning** book of **Michael Nielsen** from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#learning_with_gradient_descent

The definition of the cost function is:

\begin{eqnarray}  C(w,b) \equiv
  \frac{1}{2n} \sum_x \| y(x) - a\|^2.
\tag{6}\end{eqnarray}

Where:

- y(x) is the output from the network for all training inputs x
- a is the vector of outputs from the network when x is input

My problem is: I couldn't find the difference between **y(x)** and a. Could anyone please explain it to me?

Thanks,

Comment: My guess: you have training data $(x,a)$ where $x$ is the sample and $a$ the true label. $y$ attempts to predict $a$ knowing $x$. So $\|y(x)-a\|$ measures the error of your prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Here y(x) is the desired value that a network should give back when we feed it with input value of x data. 
So, (y,x) = (training dataset output, training dataset input)

And "a" is the actual output from the network(not the desired output).